# ¿Cómo agregar una columna nueva a una matriz?. JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, matrices, netbeans-8.2

Teniendo una matriz 4x4

```
0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0
```

Quisiera poder agregar una columna nueva a decisión del usuario, es decir, que el usuario elija la posición donde quiere que esté la nueva columna y los valores que tendrá.

Algo como esto:

```
0  1  0  0  0
0  2  0  0  0
0  3  0  0  0
0  4  0  0  0
```

Ahi se estaría insertando una columna nueva en la posición 1, la posición cambiaría de acuerdo a lo que el usuario decida, igualmente con los valores de los elementos de la fila.

Mi código es el siguiente, pero hay un problema.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Inicializo una matriz vacía de 4x4. Todos sus valores serán 0 por defecto
    int matriz[][] = new int[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + "\t");
        }
    }

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    //La variable nuevaColumna va a almacenar la posiicón de la columna donde el usuario quiere que esté la nueva columna
    int nuevaColumna;

    System.out.print("\nIngrese la posición de la columna que desea agregar: ");
    nuevaColumna = entrada.nextInt();

    //Se piden los valores de los elementos que estarán dentro de la nueva columna y se reemplaza la columna original con la nueva columna
    for (int k = 0; k < matriz[0].length; k++) {
        System.out.print("\nIngrese el valor " + "[" + k + "," + nuevaColumna + "]: ");
        matriz[k][nuevaColumna] = entrada.nextInt();
    }

    //Se imprime nuevamente la matriz pero ahora con la columna nueva    
    System.out.print("\nNUEVA MATRIZ");
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[filas][columnas] + "\t");
        }
    }

}
```

En mi código estoy reemplazando una columna ya existente de la matriz original con la columna nueva, pero no quiero que pase eso. Quiero que se mantengan todas las columnas originales, pero que se anexe la nueva columna, es decir, quiero que la matriz nueva sea de 4x5.

Claramente al ser los arreglos bidimensionales estáticos y que no les puedo cambiar las dimensiones, pensé en hacer una nueva matriz que copiara los valores de la matriz original y que incluyera la nueva columna en la posición determinada por el usuario.

Así que intenté hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Inicializo una matriz vacía de 4x4. Todos sus valores serán 0 por defecto
    int matriz[][] = new int[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + "\t");
        }
    }

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    //La variable posNuevaColumna va a almacenar la posición de la columna donde el usuario quiere que esté la nueva columna
    int posNuevaColumna;

    System.out.print("\nIngrese la posición de la columna que desea agregar: ");
    posNuevaColumna = entrada.nextInt();

    //La matriz nueva va a tener nuevas dimensiones ya que estaremos incluyendo una nueva columna
    int matrizNueva [][] = new int [matriz.length][matriz[0].length+1];
    int [] nuevaColumna = new int [matriz.length];

    //Se ingresan los elementos de la nueva columna
    for (int k = 0; k < matriz.length; k++) {
        System.out.print("Inserte el elemento " + "[" + posNuevaColumna + "," + k + "]: ");
        nuevaColumna[k] = entrada.nextInt();
    }

    //Se imprime nuevamente la matriz pero ahora con la columna nueva    
    System.out.print("\nNUEVA MATRIZ");
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[filas][columnas] + nuevaColumna[k] + "\t");
        }
    }

}
```

Pero la verdad no consigo la forma de hacer que se anexe esa columna en la posición deseada y con los valores deseados. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si consigo explicarme. Si no es así, dímelo e intento ser mas claro.

Para rellenar la nueva matriz, debes iterar sobre ella, en base a su tamaño(segundo for, que es el tamaño de columnas)

Luego, en el momento de iterar en las columnas (segundo bucle), comprueba si el indice de la columna es el de la nueva que quieres insertar.

¿Por qué una variable auxiliar? Para controlar la inserción de la nueva columna. Probablemente lo veas mejor con un ejemplo:

- Si insertamos en la columna 2, una traza sería:

valor= 0;

posnuevaColumna = 2;

En el segundo bucle for:

- Columnas = 0 -> Inserta matriz original[filas] [0] -> (columnas-valor)(0-0=0)
- Columnas = 1 -> Inserta matriz original[filas] [1] -> (columnas-valor)(1-0=1)
- Columnas = 2 -> Inserta Nuevacolumnas[filas] -> 0. valor = 1
- Columnas = 3 -> Inserta matriz original[filas] [2] (columnas-valor)(3-1=2)
- Columnas = 4 -> Inserta matriz original[filas] [3](columnas-valor(4-1=3).

  ```
      for (int filas = 0; filas < matrizNueva.length; filas++) {   
            int valor = 0;
            for (int columnas = 0; columnas < matrizNueva[0].length; columnas++) {
                 if (columnas == posNuevaColumna) {
                    matrizNueva[filas][columnas] = nuevaColumna[filas];
                    valor = 1;
                 }              
                 else
                     matrizNueva[filas][columnas] = matriz[filas][columnas-valor];

            }
      }
  ```

--Edición--
Añadir filas:

```
 int valor = 0; 

       for (int filas = 0; filas < matrizNueva.length; filas++) {        
              for (int columnas = 0; columnas < matrizNueva[0].length; columnas++) {
                   if (filas == posNuevaFila) {
                      matrizNueva[filas][columnas] = nuevaColumna[columnas];
                      valor = 1;
                   }              
                   else
                       matrizNueva[filas][columnas] = matriz[filas-valor][columnas];

              }
        }
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu comentario, me ayudó mucho. Tengo una pregunta, si quisiera hacer el mismo ejercicio pero ahora con las filas, es decir, agregar una fila en determinado lugar con determinados valores a decisión del usuario, ¿qué tendría que tener en cuenta?

Comment: Edité la respuesta, que seguro lo ves mejor. Con sacar la variable "valor" fuera del primer for, comprobar por filas e insertar el valor en una única iteración del primer bucle, lo tendrías.

Para todos estos ejercicios, de cara a entenderlos, lo mejor es coger papel y lápiz y hacer una traza completa de los valores que va cogiendo cada variable en cada iteración de los bucles.